# How to prevent a new rand() being generated after cin in c?

Tags: c++

How do i prevent a new value of `rand()` being generated from `cin`? I am building a program and if the user does not input the correct input, `srand()` still retains its value until the user inputs the correct value.

How do i set up my loops to do this?

For example, if I am looking for only numbers between 1 - 6. If the `rand()` value is 994 for example, if the user inputs the letter A, then the rand() value is still 994 until a number is input.

```
while(user input is a number){
    if(rand()%6 == 1){
        if(userNumber == 1){
        cout << "Your roll is 1.  Please roll again: "
        cin >> userRoll;

        else{
        cout << "Invalid roll.  Please roll again: "
        cin >> userRoll;
        }
    }
    else if(rand()%6 == 0){
        if(userNumber == 1){
        cout << "Your roll is Blue.  Please roll again: "
        cin >> userRoll;
        }
        else{
        cout << "Invalid roll.  Please roll again: "
        cin >> userRoll;
        }
    }
}
```

so the srand has two different paths but if the roll is invalid, I would like the value of rand to stay the same so that it would still be in the userNumber == 1 or userNumber == 0 path.

Comment: Please show what you are trying to do.

Comment: rand and cin are completely unrelated. Please post some code that illustrates your issue.

Comment: Why not store your random number until the user matches it? And then generate another one.

Comment: Still unclear to me. Could you show us your code ?

Comment: `rand()` produces a new value *every time you call it*. If you want to keep the value, store it somewhere, don't call it twice.

Comment: Or see the seed for rand.

Comment: I edited in some sample code of what I am trying to aim for.

Answer (score 1):

Save the return of `rand()` and use `rand()` only once:

```
int some_random_number = rand();
while(user input is a number){
    if(some_random_number % 6 == 1){
        // ... snip ...
    }
    else if(some_random_number % 6 == 0){
        // ... snip ...
    }
}
```

While you're fixing your code, have a look at [`rand()` considered harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).